# Rails: Is there a Way to Determine if a Viewer is Looking from Portrait or Landscape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 5 app, I want to make the menu show options if the person is looking at it on a tablet in portrait orientation than if they're looking on a tablet in landscape.

I'm using the [Browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser) gem to check if the person is on a tablet.

My view looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar"> 
  <% if browser.device.tablet? %>
    <li> 
      <%= link_to "Shop", shop_path %>
    </li>  

    # how do I check if someone is viewing in portrait orientation? 
    <li>          
      <%= link_to "About", about_path %> 
    </li>
    # end portrait orientation        

  <% end %>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to check page orientation using Ruby?  Thanks!

Comment: You could use Bootstrap to check device width or even simple media queries.

Comment: Thanks @Dithanial, do you have an example of how you would change the actual content through CSS?  Obviously, you can change the appearance, but how do you change the content thru CSS, like in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bootstrap, you can force things to be visible only on certain device widths.

```
<nav class="navbar"> 
  <% if browser.device.tablet? %>
    <li> 
      <%= link_to "Shop", shop_path %>
    </li>  

    # how do I check if someone is viewing in portrait orientation? 
    <li class="visible-xs visible-sm"> <!-- this is only visible below 768px -->       
      <%= link_to "About", about_path %> 
    </li>
    # end portrait orientation        

  <% end %>
</nav>
```

More information on Bootstrap can be found [in their docs.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)
Also, there are many guides around on how to integrate bootstrap with rails if you need one.

Comment: I like this approach (more convenient), but how should this code be adapted to avoid potential issues when a screen is small (i.e. less than 768px) in both portrait and landscape?

Comment: There are so many situations involved with responsive web development that it's impossible to cover everything here. It really depends on what you want and how you want things to look. The best thing to do is manipulate your media queries in CSS when you need to and use your browser's developer tools to see what your page will look like at each width. With Rails comes Sass, and you can use nested media queries to focus on each element to make them appear exactly how you want them at every width.

Comment: I went with this solution because I'd rather not add more JS.  Got this to work for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method to detect orientation with Ruby, but you can use jQuery Mobile for that, using the `orientationchange` event:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
  // your code...
});
```

For example:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
  if(window.orientation == 0) {
     // 0 is for portrait
     $('portrait-only').show();
  } else { 
     $('portrait-only').hide();
  }
});
```

Now, on your form, add an `id` to the `<li>` tag:

```
<li id="portrait-only">          
  <%= link_to "About", about_path %> 
</li>
```

This will hide/show that element every time the device is rotated.

To detect on initial load, just check `window.orientation` on load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.orientation == 0) {
      // same as above
    }
)};
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way I can adjust the code in your example, to make it two completely different menu's?  For example, if it's portrait show <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="portrait-menu">, but if it's landscape show <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="landscape-menu">?

Comment: @yellowreign Sure, use two `ul` tags (one with portrait menu and the other with landscape menu) with different `id` each and in your script call `show()` in one and `hide()` in the other.

Comment: Wait, if it's two different versions, wouldn't it be show and show (instead of show and hide), if it's two different versions (as opposing to showing additional content).  Or is there a risk of showing both menus?

Comment: @yellowreign You are free to add/remove or show/hide any element in your page upon any event, in your case, using `orientationchange`.

Comment: @yellowreign Yes, there is a risk, if i understood correctly, you will show just one according to orientation. So, if you show both, you will have to menus at the same time, thus the need to hide one while showing the other.